# Jasper report parameters

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm new to *JasperReports Server* and I'm using *iReport* 4.0.1 for jrxml design. Just want to ask if I put some new values in the parameter map when calling JasperFillManager.fillReport, Do I have to create some new parameters in ireport regarding the keys I set in the parameter map when calling JasperFillManager.fillReport or all the new parameters will be inside "REPORT_PARAMETER_MAP"?

For example:

```
Map parameters = new HashMap();

parameters.put("value1", value1);

parameters.put("value2",value2);

JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(myProgramStream, parameters,  jasperReportDS);
```

So in ireport, the value1 and value2 have already been in REPORT_PARAMETER_MAP or I have to create two new parameters named "value1" and "value2" in the related jrxml?

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So in ireport, the value1 and value2 have already been in
>   REPORT_PARAMETER_MAP or I have to create two new parameters named
>   "value1" and "value2" in the related jrxml?

-You have to create two new parameters named value1 and value2 in jrxml.

Answer (score 0):

it is necessary to create to create two new parameters named "value1" and "value2" in the related jrxml. Otherwise not worked.